# Custom URL schemes ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

Alright I think I am close to a solution here. I think I must be missing something small. Hope you guy can help.'

I am trying to have another app open another custom app and run a method from that app that is being called through the URL scheme. I understand that in ios 9 they made it manitory to define in the info.plist the key

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>URLScheme0</string>
    <string>URLScheme1</string>
    <string>URLScheme2</string>
    ect....
</array>
```

And I think I have done that properly. Though I want a confirm on this and other thing. Firstly, do I add this to the info.plist of the "calling" app, or the "receiving" app, or BOTH? As, I have it now it is with both. When I remove it from the calling apps plist I get the error.

"This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx”

Keep in mind I have also included in the plist for the receiving app the URL types and URL schemes array with the same scheme names.

The the calling app I have a button mapped with this methods code:

```
- (IBAction)killMethod:(id)sender {

NSString *customURL = @"TurnOffRelay://";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];

} else {

    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"URL error" message:@"No custom URL defined for Kill Relay" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

}

and for the receiving app I have in the appDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application OpenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *) sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

NSLog(@" Calling application: %@", sourceApplication);
NSLog(@"URL scheme: %@", [url scheme]);

if ([sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"net.ble.relay"]) {

    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"TurnOffRelay://"]) {

        ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [viewController killSwitch];

        NSLog(@"Running killSwitch");

    }

return YES;

}

else

    return NO;
```

}

With what I have right now running I am able to actually press the button in the "calling" app and from there the "receiving" app opens, but alas, the method I want to run doesn't run inside of the if statements. I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I will gladly answer any questions about things I may have missed. This has been bothering me all day. Would like some sort of guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and a given scheme in the app that calls `canOpenURL:` on the given scheme.

Comment: FYI - your method name is wrong. You have `application:OpenURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. The `O` in `Open` needs to be `o`. Case matters.

Comment: Be aware that the schemes are case-sensitive for purposes of matching against the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list.  An entry for `CustomUrl` will not match a call to `...openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"customURL"]]`.

Comment: I've triple checked Case for both LS and URL Schemes. I'll test the lower case openURL. Get back.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to   `if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"TurnOffRelay://"])` 。 url scheme is **TurnOffRelay** rather than **TurnOffRelay://**.

Answer (score 0):

So, after changing the OpenURL to openURL and then noticing that the sourceApplication name was wrong. I am guessing that if I had typed in the correct application to use, as in, the actual name of the application that was "calling" the If block would have proceeded correctly. But I am sure, also, that if I had not changed the openURL I would have been stuck again.

Thanks for the help. Its now working as intended.